# Issues of executing remote powershell script using cake-build

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, cakebuild

I am trying to execute  following `test.ps1` script

```
param([string]$name,[string]$password);
write-Output "Hello $($name) my password is  $($password)";
dir c:\
New-Item c:\HRTemp\test.txt -ItemType file
```

on remote server using following command

```
StartPowershellScript("Invoke-Command", args =>
{
    args.Append("ScriptBlock", "{{c:\\test.ps1 -name dato -password test}}" );
});
```

I was able to successfully invoke this command from command line and now I want the same using cake script.

I am using [Cake.Powershell](https://github.com/SharpeRAD/Cake.Powershell) addin.

When I try to execute it with one curly brace `{c:\\test.ps1 -name dato -password test}` ,   I am getting error:

`Error: Input string was not in a correct format.`

When I try it with two curly brace

`{{c:\\test.ps1 -name dato -password test}}`

output is the following

`Executing: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {{c:\test.ps1 -name dato -password test}}`

but, when I check on remote server test.txt file is not created.

Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the different handling of curly braces by the `ProcessArgumentBuilder` used internally by the Cake.Powershell addin, and the format parser used internally in Cake's internal logger.

I submitted a PR to Cake.Powershell which has now been merged and a new release published, so upgrading to [version 0.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Powershell/0.2.7) will resolve this issue for you.

You should then be able to use something like the following:

```
StartPowershellScript("Invoke-Command", args =>
{
    args.Append("hostname").Append("-ScriptBlock {c:\\test.ps1 -name dato - password test}");
});
```

And while the log will include double braces, the actual command will only use single braces and should run correctly.

Comment: now I am getting     Error: C:/BuildAgent/work/f4bd1e7f8392f527/TeamCityTest/Cake/build.cake(128,1): error CS8000: This language feature ('Label in interactive') is not yet implemented in Roslyn.

Comment: Okay I think that must be a different issue. Check [this repo](https://github.com/agc93/cake-ps-sample) for a sample of what I described working fine, so at least the brackets part is fixed.